# Angular2 RC5 - Ngmodule

Tags: angular

I am working on sample Nodejs application using Angular2 RC5.
I am aware that in angular2 RC5 , ngModule has been introduced.
My sample application has 4 screens , and this NOT a single page application.

My question do I need to create 4 root modules each for a screen

OR

Only 1 root module is enough.

Am not sure if my question makes sense.

Comment: Seems like each of your separate points is an SPA. So I guess you need separate root modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more about the architecture of your app and the vision you have about it, how you want to extend it, and how requirements are fixed and clear, if the screens are each one related to a separate part of the system and can be separated, then I would create one root module (app.module) and then consider 4 sub modules for my app (either lazy loaded or eager loaded based on the requirements)
you can find more about the architecture in the following:
[Architecture Overview](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to make a multi-window application with Angular2 is to open your application multiple times (with parameterized URLs) using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and then you can pass messages between the windows using [`otherWindow.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Modules are orthogonal to this problem.